# Apparent deadlock with latest c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I am using hibernate 5.1.0 and c3p0 0.9.5.1. I do not have caching enabled and I'm getting `Apparent Deadlock` error.

```
(C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v2d5k9y3ipope1s0apgi|4b76251c]-AdminTaskTimer) com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@2a94bd11 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status:
        Managed Threads: 3
        Active Threads: 3
        Active Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@2ece5321
                        on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v2d5k9y3ipope1s0apgi|4b76251c]-HelperThread-#2
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@736e6fcf
                        on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v2d5k9y3ipope1s0apgi|4b76251c]-HelperThread-#1
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5ceffb3c
                        on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v2d5k9y3ipope1s0apgi|4b76251c]-HelperThread-#0
        Pending Tasks:
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@75425131
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@29c943e3
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@29d94102
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@a4c691e
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6d606abf
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@ed5eaab
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6de76b22
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@40aeb19
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6a514cb5
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@4b7073e6
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1d18afd1
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@4e19dd48
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@2ecd04da
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@666abda6
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3ed4e09d
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3ea78992
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@788aa148
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@4bbea472
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@52f76590
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@509e9d45
Pool thread stack traces:
        Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2v2d5k9y3ipope1s0apgi|4b76251c]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
                java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
                java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
                java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
                java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
                java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
                java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
                java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
                java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
                com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:243)
                com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
                com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
                com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
                com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
                com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
                com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
                sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
                com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
                com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
```

My c3p0 config is as:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class = "org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider";
hibernate.c3p0.min_size = "200";
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = "200";
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = "100";
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = "0";
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = "86400";
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery = "select 1";
```

Any idea why I am getting deadlock scenario. From what I read on the net caching is the main culprit which causes this scenario to occur bet I don't have caching enabled.

Comment: Apparent Deadlock error in c3p0 is sometimes a problem of your network or database server. Can you acces the same database in another application from your pc?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to access the DB from MySQL workbench from my local pc. The system I'm trying to access DB from is a remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Your application's attempts to acquire Connections from the database are hanging, neither succeeding nor failing with an Exception. These frozen Connection acquisition attempts are exhausting the thread pool. You need to debug why the attempts to Connect are hanging. Nowadays, that's often due to the security / firewall policies governing cloud-hosted infrastructure.